# comments to a contributor of an answer

Tags: discussion, comments

How is it possible to alert a contributor of an answer of your post that you have answered to him ?

In other words, to put his name in color in comments.

I didn't find back the manipulation to this.

Sorry for this question which is not very interesting from a mathematica point of view. But, it didn't find it in the help of the forum.

Comment: Use the @ before his/her username?

Comment: @Emy Thank you you. But on long names and may be in old posts, it seems to me that it doesn't work

Comment: @Bendesarts If you comment on an answer, the person who wrote the answer will be notified.  If you want to notify a commenter, you need to use the `@` syntax.  It is not possible to notify someone who is neither the author of the answer, nor commented on it.  Notifications are in-website only, so if the person hasn't opened StackExchange, s/he will not receive the notification.